# Prove that $\{\beta \in S_5 \mid \beta(1)=1, \beta(3)=3\}$ is a subgroup of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Let $H = \{\beta \in S_5 \mid \beta(1)=1, \beta(3)=3\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_5$. How many elements does $H$ contain?  Will the conclusion change if you change $S_5$ to $S_n$ for $n \geq 3$?  How many elements are in $H$ if $S_5$ replaced by $A_n$ for $n \geq 4$?

It is relatively easy to get there are $6$ elements in $H$, but how to prove that it is a subgroup? List all elements and check them based on two-step subgroup test step by step rather than using a abstract method? If I can do it, how to prove or disprove in an $n$ situation?

Answer (score 3):

This is exercise 34 in chapter 5 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Basically, since two numbers are fixed, you want to count the numbers of permutations of $n-2$ elements.

In $S_5$ that's $(5-2)! = 3! = 6$. In $S_n$ that's $(n-2)!$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what's known as a stabilizer subgroup.

For the subgroup test, you need to verify that, given $\sigma, \tau \in H$,

1) The product $\sigma\tau\in H$. Remember that being in $H$ simply means that you're in $S_n$ and don't move around 1 or 3. If both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ keep them fixed (i.e., $\sigma(1) = 1 = \tau(1)$), what can you say about their composition?

2) That the inverse $\sigma^{-1} \in H$. Again, it's all about how $\sigma$ moves numbers around. If $\sigma$ fixes both 1 and 3 (that is, $\sigma(1) = 1$ and $\sigma(3) = 3$), does its inverse necessarily do the same?

To find the size of $H$ considering it as a subgroup $S_n$ for any $n\geq3$, think about this: Permutations in $H$ can move all the numbers besides 1 and 3 any way they want, right? So it seems like they should behave an awfully lot like the symmetric group on the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\} - \{1, 3\}$. Does this agree with $H$ having size 6 as a subgroup of $S_5$?

If $H \subseteq S_n$ does behave like a smaller symmetric group, what would its size have to be if we restrict our attention to only the even permutations in $A_n$? It would have to contain only the even permutations in the smaller symmetric group.